# Escaping html entities in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea used for comments that loads the contents of a div when a link is pressed, putting those contents in the displayed textarea.

Everything worked fine until I introduced a way to display interpoints (I'm talking about the `&middot;` entity). These display fine in the div, but the problem is they also display as dots in the actual textarea, which I don't want. I want them to display as `{*}` in the textarea, since this is the string that gets converted to `&middot;` on the server side.

This is the function I use to handle the display of tags:

```
function HtmlDecode(str) 
{
    var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
    ta.innerHTML = str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/&middot;/g, "{*}");
    toReturn = ta.value;
    ta = null;

    return toReturn.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, "\n");
}
```

I output the textarea like this:

```
anotherDiv.innerHTML = '<textarea ...>' + HtmlDecode(div.innerHTML) + '</textarea>';
```

What I don't understand is why if I change the `/&middot;/g` replace with `/asdf/g` for example, any `asdf` will get replaced just fine.

Bottom line: how can I make my textarea display `{*}` instead of an actual interpoint?

Comment: The symbol is called [interpunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) :P

Answer (score 1):

What about `.replace(/·/g, "{*}")` instead of `.replace(/&middot;/g, "{*}");`?

Comment: Same thing, no replacing takes place.

Comment: can you post how parameter str looks like?

Comment: div.innerHTML = `2&middot;5 = 10 asdf` (this is what's in the database, and also what shows up in view -> source)

Comment: if you debug it with firebug, is that the value passed as a parameter?

Comment: I just checked, and apparently not. The valued passed contains the actual interpoint, not the entity. Any ideas why? And shouldn't your suggestion work in this case? Why doesn't that work either?

Comment: it seems like the parameter is giving you the decoded html, i thought of that because you were using the actual < in your first replacement

Comment: it seems like the parameter is giving you the decoded html, I thought of that because you were using the actual < in your first replacement, but, yes, if that's what the string contains, it should replace it. I don't know what's the issue with it not replacing it. Whe you debug it, does the result string of your method looks the same? I mean without any replacement? Maybe a little working example.

Comment: Yes, the result string is with no replacement.

Comment: Could it have something to do with my page encoding (it's utf-8)? When I view the javascript source in the browser, the interpoint doesn't display correctly, it displays as a question mark.

Comment: I don't think so, with utf-8 you should be good. You have this code in the database, how are you enconding it before putting it on the page? I would start by just replacing the character in the database and see if this all works as expected for other characters. Then maybe trying other encoding.

Comment: The database collation is utf8-general-ci. I'm adding `&middot;` to the database. The reason why I dont want my textarea to display the actual middot is that, if I add the actual dot to my database, it gets saved as `&Acirc;&middot;` for some reason. But I'll probably just end up removing the `&Acirc;` on the server side and leave it like that.